# Receive File via SFTP/SSH and automatically forward to FTP on another server

Tags: ftp, sftp

I'm currently in a situation where I receive flat files via FTP from my clients.  A couple of clients have insisted on the need to use SSH Private Key SFTP rather than regular FTP.

What I want to do is setup a web server (preferably in linux/unix but I guess I can do it on a windows server and purchase SFTP server software) that will do the following:

1. Allow me to setup an SFTP directory for each client with unique user/pass.  Each directory also has to have the public/private key SSH "stuff" I'm a little new to this but I've googled it.
2. Once the file is completely uploaded by the client, I want to kick off an event that ftp's that file via regular FTP to my Windows cloud.
3. These files can be up to 10mb so the even that ftp's to the other server can't fire until the file is completely uploaded.

Has anyone set something like this up?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't this be abusing the trust of your clients? Presumably your clients prefer SFTP because their data will be encrypted when it crosses the public Internet. Unless the SFTP server communicates with your FTP server within the cloud on a private network, you'll still end up sending them unencrypted over the Internet albeit from your own server instead of theirs.

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that this data is all public information and there is nothing sensitive in it.  Some of my clients just have a policy that they cannot regular FTP out... only SFTP with SSH Key.  Interestingly enough, my windows cloud does support the "SFTP" protocol but not with the whole SSH key thing.  So I could use that when I forward the file to the windows cloud.  Bottom line is regular FTP to the windows cloud is fine.  I've been able to talk most of my clients into using regular FTP but I've got a stubborn couple here that I need this solution for.

Comment: If they support SFTP, it would be unusual to find an implementation that doesn't support public key authentication. Of course, your cloud provider may make it impossible for you to actually configure it so then it'd be no use. If you need to find out what software the server is, you could try "ssh -v <server>" on a Linux client and you should see "remote software version..." somewhere in the debug output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Linux, you can use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to monitor the directory the files will be SFTP'd to and have it trigger your ftp job. It's kind of like cron except that instead of triggering jobs based on time, it does so based on filesystem modifications. In order to only trigger once the entire file has been written, I think you can use IN_CLOSE_WRITE in the inotify mask. Failing this, I suggest configuring events for each of the events individually to echo a message to a log file and see if you can identify one which reliably happens only at the end of the SFTP transfer.

If you're using RedHat, it's not in the standard distribution, but it is in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: incron seems like it could be a pretty sweet solution.  Do you have any recommendations on a simple linux/sftp setup?  In other words, is their an sftp software you would recommend for a particular flavor of linux?

Comment: Just about all modern Linux distros include OpenSSH which supports SFTP with public key authentication. It's actually a seperate subsystem within OpenSSH but both RedHat and Ubuntu enable it by default.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows you could use [Titan FTP Server](http://www.webdrive.com/products/titanftp/) Enterprise Edition, which supports SFTP as well as allows you to define various types of events. When the event is triggered, you could kick off anything you need on a per folder/per account basis.

PS. AFAIK, when it comes to SFTP it is either password authentication or public key authentication (SSH key), but not both.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the password vs. public key, I knew I was missing something on the terminology, I've got it now thanks.

Comment: Even if rare, I have seen some setups requiring both public-key and password/keyboard-interactive authentication.

Answer (score 4):

In your UNIX server, you can configure SSH to use a custom sftp server that instead of handling SFTP protocol itself, opens a new SSH connection to to the Windows SFTP server using password authentication and forwards the SFTP traffic there.

Writting the proxy is easy with the right tools, for instance, in Perl using the [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# this is the sftp-proxy-server

use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($windows_server, $user, $passwd);
$ssh->system({ssh_opts => '-s'}, 'sftp');
$ssh->error and die $ssh->error;
```

You can instruct the SSH server to use that alternative SFTP server changing the configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. For instance:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/local/bin/sftp-proxy-server
```

Comment: Better idea than using incron. Only, if the sftp-proxy-server could be written in Python, it is more manageable these days among younger users.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try apache FTP Serveur ?

I think you can do what you need with the ftplet API.

see :
http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/index.html