# Java application needs exclusive access to file being delivered by sftp

Tags: java, ubuntu, sftp

Environment: Java 7 on an Ubuntu 12 server.

I have a Java application that polls for incoming `.zip` files that are delivered via `sftp`. I have no control over the client that's delivering the files.

The files being delivered are quite large, and in some cases, the poll mechanism detects a file while it's still being written. In this situation, the Java application borks because it thinks the file is corrupt.

What's the most effective way of detecting when the local `sftp` server has finished writing the file?

Comment: Could you please rephrase that? What exactly do you mean by "that polls for incoming .zip files"?

Comment: I periodically check whether a ZIP file has appeared in a directory. I then unzip the file and do some processing on the files in it.

Comment: I understand you have no control over the client that delivers the files, but can't you ask these people to, at least, make available a MD5 hash so you can check the integrity of the package before trying to unzip it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of approaches to dealing with this.  You can choose one, but the more you implement the better:

- The sender should upload as a .tmp file, then rename to .zip once done so that the watcher only sees the finished file.
- The watcher should check the last modified time of the file, and if it was modified in the last 10 seconds (maybe 1 minute) then ignore the file and try again later.
- If your OS supports it, try to get an exclusive lock on the file before reading it.  This is not so easy in java, and depends on OS specifics.
- Always send the file as a zip file, as if the file is incomplete of otherwise corrupted it will fail the CRC check.  Also you get the added benefit for smaller transfers, smaller archive folder etc.  (Of course you are already doing this, as mentioned in the question).

Look at the [File2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) component of camel and look at all the options it gives you.  Make you want to use Camel, right?

Comment: As noted, I have no control over the sender.

Comment: Yes, I noticed, but wanted my answer to be complete for this general situation.  As it's a common one.

Comment: It would be the ideal solution, but I've got no chance of getting that changed. I'm receiving data from a Control-M job running on an enterprise SAP server — and it's a world of pain getting anything like that changed.

Comment: Your second option is probably the way I'll go…

Comment: Tell me about it!  Same deal where ever I look.  Going to add one more 'best practice' to my list...

Comment: In my own system, I read the whole folder tree and store it in the DB.  Then at the next poll, I compare the trees and any changed files that have not been recently modified get imported.  The advantage of this method is that I can pick up files that are delivered while my app is down or being restarted.

Answer (score 0):

See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5851185/92063 which mentions [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en). You can use it to notify your application that a file system event has taken place.

A quote from the linked website:

> **incron :: inotify cron system**
>
> This program is an "inotify cron" system. It consists of a daemon and
>   a table manipulator. You can use it a similar way as the regular cron.
>   The difference is that the inotify cron handles filesystem events
>   rather than time periods.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the sender, that is unfortunate because the best solution would be the following (I will give another solution afterwards which doesn't require the sender to change anything).

**The sender should rename the file when the upload is finished.**

E.g. the file is named `fileInProgress.txt` during upload and `fileFinished.txt` when the upload is finished. You will restrict your java program to only watch for files with the name *Finished.txt. This is the easiest and an absolute reliable solution.

---

Your solution would be the following.

- From your java program do a file-listing on the upload folder and store the file-sizes.
- Wait for 10 secs (or longer if you want to be on the save side).
- Do a file-listing again.
- All files that didn't change in size are finished and can be processed.

Note that this does not give you absolute certainity that the upload is finished but it comes closer the longer the interval between your file size check is.

Answer (score 0):

As [David Roussel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/191084/david-roussel) mentioned, Camel would be very useful for this. Take a look at *initialDelay* (among any others you may find useful) from [File2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) as this would place a specified delay before it polls the directory.

Any sort of file polling that I have done I have used Camel as it is easier to handle these kinds of situations.