# SFTP to FTP bridge

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, java-server

I would like to connect with an SFTP client to an FTP server using java. I know the two technologies have nothing to do with each-other. What I'm trying to accomplish is to connect to an FTP server via the internet with out using two ports or changing the server configuration.

Is there any SFTP->FTP bridge in java it would be great. If not, how can I accomplish that ?

I would like to incorporate this in an exciting java server so hence, java based solutions are preferred. If there is some standalone software which you can control via code than it should support windows and *nix.

(Since SFTP is just the means here, a similar WebDav solution will also work)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Receive File via SFTP/SSH and automatically forward to FTP on another server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849758/receive-file-via-sftp-ssh-and-automatically-forward-to-ftp-on-another-server)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl while that question is helpfull. That isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a full SFTP->FTP bridge while this question deals with publishing file only.

Comment: OK. Btw, you should specify what platform you need the bridge to run on. Also I believe you should remove the Java tag as this is not about Java actually.

Comment: I need to develop this in java. I should clarify that.

Comment: can you remove the close ?

Answer (score -1):

You could go with trial and error. Try this out see if it works.

[How to retrieve a file from a server via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-sftp-a-file-from-a-server)